# PHP Convert eregi() string to preg_match or preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, eregi

please can someone help me with convert this string from eregi() to preg_match or preg_replace? Thank you very much!

```
$eregicheck = "^([-!#\$%&'*+./0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~])+@([-!#\$%&'*+/0-9=?A-Z^_`a-z{|}~]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\$";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
$pregcheck = "(".$eregicheck.")i";
```

Done.

Comment: @jeroen Matching brackets (of any type - parens, brace, square...) can be used as delimiters, with the added advantage of not needing any escaping (since they come in pairs). Parentheses are my personal preference because they remind me that the entire match is the first element of the match array.

Comment: Wow, didn't know that, that's going to be useful...

Comment: +1 for the delimiters, the i modifier isn't needed

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte In the general case, `eregi` to `preg` requires the `i` modifier. In this particular case, though, you're right, because of the `a-z` and `A-Z` both being present.